# Can I marry a resident in Spain if I am not from European Union?

Tags: marriage, spain

My boyfriend is a resident in Spain. I am a not from European Union.

We can't get married in our hometown because of some problems. Is it possible for us to get married is Spain or can he sponsor me?

Comment: Is your boyfriend an EU citizen?

Comment: Assuming he isn't an EU citizen, what kind of 'resident' is he?

Answer (score 2):

From [Getting married in Spain: Marriage and partnerships in Spain](http://www.expatica.com/es/family-essentials/Weddings-in-Spain-Getting-married-in-Spain_102734.html), yes it is possible.

> When neither of the parties is a Spanish citizen one of them must usually be legally resident in Spain for the previous two years. Obviously, if one of the couple is a Spanish citizen no residence period applies. There may be variations across Spanish regions and so it is advisable to check with the Civil Registry Office in the area where you wish to get married as to their specific requirements.   A list of Civil Registries and further information regarding civil marriage in Spain can by found by regions on the Spanish Ministry for Justice’s website.

However, note that in the last years many weddings were reported to be arranged solely for the purpose of obtaining residence. For this, Spanish authorities tend to very strict and perform a test to the couple in order to see if it is a real marriage or just some kind of arrangement.